# Xamarin Forms, quickly pressing the button opens 2x the same window

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

When I click on the icon that redirects to a new window, it opens the same view twice. And I do not know how to deal with it to open only one view.

example xaml button

```
<local:AnimatedImage Grid.Column="2" Source="googlemap_view_search.png"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="16,0">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </local:AnimatedImage>
```

Custom Animated Image class

```
 public class AnimatedImage : Image
{
    private const int ANIMATED_TIME = 100;
    private const double INITIAL_VALUE = 1;
    private const double MAGNIFICATION_VALUE = 1.3;

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create<AnimatedImage, ICommand>(p => p.Command, null);
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create<AnimatedImage, object>(p => p.CommandParameter, null);
    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    private ICommand TransitionCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                this.AnchorX = 0.48;
                this.AnchorY = 0.48;
                await this.ScaleTo(MAGNIFICATION_VALUE, 50, Easing.Linear);
                await Task.Delay(ANIMATED_TIME);
                await this.ScaleTo(INITIAL_VALUE, 50, Easing.Linear);
                if (Command != null)
                {
                    Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public AnimatedImage()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
        {
            Command = TransitionCommand
        });
    }
}
```

}

And in ViewModel public DelegateCommand SearchCommand { get; private set; } and

```
    await NavigateToPage(new SearchPage());
```

Comment: Returning `new Command` every time the getter is called?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while you `await` the animations before executing the search command, there is nothing preventing the user from initiating the command again. You can add a boolean variable that is set to `true` when you enter the command and if the command is already executing you ignore the second user tap.

```
private ICommand TransitionCommand
{
    get
    {
        bool isExecuting = false;
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            if(isExecuting) return;
            isExecuting = true
            try
            {
                this.AnchorX = 0.48;
                this.AnchorY = 0.48;
                await this.ScaleTo(MAGNIFICATION_VALUE, 50, Easing.Linear);
                await Task.Delay(ANIMATED_TIME);
                await this.ScaleTo(INITIAL_VALUE, 50, Easing.Linear);
                if (Command != null)
                {
                    Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
                }
             }
             finally 
             {
                  isExecuting = false;
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin `Command` has [CanExecute](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Command.CanExecute/p/System.Object/) method which can be used to prevent the execution of command depending on your business logic.

```
public ICommand SearchCommand {get; private set; }

bool _canSearch = true;
public bool CanSearch 
{ 
    get { return _canSearch; } 
    private set { 
        _canSearch = value;
        ((Command)SearchCommand).ChangeCanExecute(); 
    }
}

public SearchPageViewModel()
{
    SearchCommand = new Command(() => DoSearchStuff(), () => CanSearch)
}

void DoSearchStuff()
{
    CanSearch = false;
    // long searching stuff
    CanSearch = true;
}
```

Hope this helps